# avoid loops and increase performance to update a dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dict of the form:

> dict1[element1] : reference1
>
> dict1[element2] : reference2
>
> dict1[element3] : reference2

There a some elements have the same reference (like `element2` and `element3` have).
I need to convert this into a dict with the following form:

> dict2[reference1] : [element1]
>
> dict2[reference2] : [element2,element3]

To get this I wrote:

```
dict2=dict()
for key in dict1:
    UpdateDict(dict2,dict1[key],key)

def UpdateDict(Dict,Key,Entry):
    Keys = list(Dict.keys())
    if Key in Keys:
        Dict[Key].append(Entry)
        return
    else:
        Item = list()
        Item.append(Entry)
        Dict[Key] = Item
    return
```

This works fine until `dict1` is not very large, but if `dict1` is large (some 1000 keys) it takes hours to get the result.

Is there a faster way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
Keys = list(Dict.keys())
if Key in Keys:
    ...
```

is probably the main culprit. It turns a O(1) lookup (`if Key in Dict:`) into a O(n) one. This plus the overhead of the one-function-call per key is certainly suboptimal indeed.

A much simpler solution is to use a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def revindex(dic):
    rev = defaultdict(list)
    # nb for py2.7 use `iteritems()` instead
    for k, v in dic.items():
        rev[v].append(k)
    return rev


dict2 = revindex(dict1)
```

Comment: Only answer to correctly identify and explain the actual performance issue instead of just providing shorter/simpler code.

Comment: @tobias_k true, its a nice answer. Considering the OP tagged python 3x I would change that iteritems to items though. +1

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead of a vanilla dict to avoid those membership checks and you can remove the function calls which adds a non trivial overhead with repeated calls:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dct2 = defaultdict(list)
for k in dct1:
   dct2[dct1[k]].append(k)
```

Comment: I have not benchmarked it but using `dict.items()` (or `dict.iteritems()` in py2) might be a bit faster by avoiding the `__getitem_` calls.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers added a small test in my answer for a generic dict of size 100000. For that dict at least you are right

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defaultdicts that were already mentioned, you could also create the dict with the setdefault method, like so:

```
def transform(some_dict):
    new_dict = {}
    for k, v in some_dict.items():
        new_dict.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
    return new_dict
```

There is no need for the if statement you made. In my benchmark, this is around 2 times faster than your method. The method of Moses Koledoye beats those (on my machine) for some reason, which is in turn beaten by bruno desthuilliers' method.
For the dictionary

```
dict1 = dict([(str(x),x%10) for x in range(0,100000)])
```

I get (transform_0 being your method with together with the for loop, transform_d Moses' and transform_d2 being Bruno's methods) as average over 200 calls:

> benchmark for "transform_0": 133.516 ms
>
> benchmark for "transform": 50.696 ms
>
> benchmark for "transform_d": 43.967 ms
>
> benchmark for "transform_d2": 38.408 ms

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers self written snippet using time.clock(), far from optimal, but good for a first hint

Comment: `timeit` would have saved you some time - no self-written snippet required ;)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers probably true, at the time I wrote that I wasn't aware of timeit though :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `defaultdict` or just `dict.setdefault`:

```
dict2 = {}
for key, value in dict1.items():
    dict2.setdefault(value, []).append(key)
```

A function seems unnecessary for such a simple call.